# Rviz or package not functioning

Tags: rviz, pcl, ros-kinetic, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3, lubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic, a Tim561 Lidar and the package sick_scan. I am able to get sick_scan to run correctly and publish data to the topic cloud. I am using rviz to make sure.

I am now trying to follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials) in order to down sample the pointcloud2 data. I am however having some issues. I believe I followed the steps correctly, however when I try to visualize the data in rviz nothing shows up. In addition, when I run `rostopic echo output` nothing appears. I would also add that on the tutorial it says to select the fixed frame as "camera_depth_frame" however this option does not appear for me(in  fact no options appear). I have tried typing it in but rviz continues being blank.

Could this be an issue with the fixed frame selection or rather with my code (which I will paste below)?

Thanks.

example.cpp

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

ros::Publisher pub;

void 
cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud_msg)
{
  // Container for original & filtered data
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2* cloud = new pcl::PCLPointCloud2; 
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr cloudPtr(cloud);
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_filtered;

  // Convert to PCL data type
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*cloud_msg, *cloud);

  // Perform the actual filtering
  pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
  sor.setInputCloud (cloudPtr);
  sor.setLeafSize (0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  sor.filter (cloud_filtered);

  // Convert to ROS data type
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
  pcl_conversions::moveFromPCL(cloud_filtered, output);

  // Publish the data
  pub.publish (output);
}

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("input", 1, cloud_cb);

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output", 1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
    <name>my_pcl_tutorial</name>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <description>The my_pcl_tutorial package</description>
    <maintainer email="ubuntu@todo.todo">ubuntu</maintainer>
    <license>TODO</license>

    <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
    <build_depend>pcl_conversions</build_depend>
    <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
    <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
    <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>pcl_conversions</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>pcl_ros</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>pcl_conversions</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>pcl_ros</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
    
    <build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
    <exec_depend>libpcl-all</exec_depend>

    <export>   
    </export>
</package>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_pcl_tutorial)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    pcl_conversions
    pcl_ros
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319278/rviz-or-package-not-functioning/) by [Pol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40249/pol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-22**:
I shortened your question significantly by removing the comments in your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files.

**Comment by [Pol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40249/pol/) on 2019-03-24**:
Ah ok thank you! Any idea on how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix this one on my own, my apologies. The tutorial tells me to run `$ rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2`, I had to change the input to cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Pol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40249/pol/) with karma: 33 on 2019-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0